# Converting a custom type to string in Go

Tags: string, go, type-conversion

In this bizarre example, someone has created a new type which is really just a string:

```
type CustomType string

const (
        Foobar CustomType = "somestring"
)

func SomeFunction() string {
        return Foobar
}
```

However, this code fails to compile:

> cannot use Foobar (type CustomType) as type string in return argument

How would you fix SomeFunction so that it is able to return the string value of Foobar ("somestring") ?

Comment: Creating a type that's just a string is not all that bizarre. For example, if a you know that certain string is always a country name you could create a `type Country string`; this will make the code easier to read.

Comment: @Akavall How about restricting `Country` type to a known list of values? Can we do that?

Comment: Is this basically go's way of doing enums?

Comment: How can we do the opposite of this, casting "string" to "CustomType"? I hit "invalid operation: (someString) (value of type string) is not an interface" with code `someString.(CustomType)`
Edit: "CustomType(someString)" seems to do the trick. It's hard to find the right documentation on casting with alias types, I only find doc for interfaces.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

[Convert](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) the value to a string:

```
func SomeFunction() string {
        return string(Foobar)
}
```

Comment: Very useful if one hasn't control over the string type-alias; in those sitations adding a `String` method is impossible.

Comment: Hi, I've tried to convert a type "ULID" to string using this cast. It does have a method "String" implementing the "Stringer" method. Why cast still doesn't work? Casting to "string" is not related to implementing the "Stringer" interface?

Answer (score 29):

Better to define a `String` function for the `Customtype` - it can make your life easier over time - you have better control over things as and if the structure evolves. If you really need `SomeFunction` then let it return `Foobar.String()`

```
   package main

    import (
        "fmt"
    )

    type CustomType string

    const (
        Foobar CustomType = "somestring"
    )

    func main() {
        fmt.Println("Hello, playground", Foobar)
        fmt.Printf("%s", Foobar)
        fmt.Println("\n\n")
        fmt.Println(SomeFunction())
    }

    func (c CustomType) String() string {
        fmt.Println("Executing String() for CustomType!")
        return string(c)
    }

    func SomeFunction() string {
        return Foobar.String()
    }
```

https://play.golang.org/p/jMKMcQjQj3

Answer (score 10):

> For every type T, there is a corresponding conversion operation T(x)
>   that converts the value x to type T. A conversion from one type to
>   another is allowed if both have the same underlying type, or if both
>   are unnamed pointer types that point to variables of the same
>   underlying type; these conversions change the type but not the
>   representation of the value. If x is assignable to T, a conversion
>   is permitted but is usually redundant.  - Taken from [The Go
>   Programming Language - by Alan A. A. Donovan](https://www.amazon.com/Programming-Language-Addison-Wesley-Professional-Computing/product-reviews/0134190440/ref=cm_cr_getr_d_paging_btm_next_4?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=4)

As per your example here are some of the different examples which will return the value.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type CustomType string

const (
    Foobar CustomType = "somestring"
)

func SomeFunction() CustomType {
    return Foobar
}
func SomeOtherFunction() string {
    return string(Foobar)
}
func SomeOtherFunction2() CustomType {
    return CustomType("somestring") // Here value is a static string.
}
func main() {
    fmt.Println(SomeFunction())
    fmt.Println(SomeOtherFunction())
    fmt.Println(SomeOtherFunction2())
}
```

It will output:

```
somestring
somestring
somestring
```

[The Go Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/v6fvjlb1DKS)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert like this:

`var i int = 42
var f float64 = float64(i)`

check [here](https://tour.golang.org/basics/13)

you can return like this:

`return string(Foobar)`