# How to make a function received different type as a string

Tags: go

In my code, I have some string types like:

```
type StringTypeOne string
type StringTYpeOwn string
```

I know I can convert them to string after reading:
[Converting a custom type to string in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45891600/converting-a-custom-type-to-string-in-go)

However I want to write a function which takes all these kind of struct, e.g.

```
func handleString(s StringType)
```

where s can be `StringTypeOne` or `StringTypeTwo` or any other type with string field.

Is this possible in golang?

Comment: @hqt: Downvotes do not require comments, and requesting them is boring and inappropriate.

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. The exact thing you're asking cannot be done in Go. But can you explain the larger problem you're trying to solve? If so, there's surely an alternate solution.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot. But for your purpose, you should implement a custom interface.

```
// define an interface that do something you need
type Doer interface {
   DoSomething();
}
```

Then you define custom type and implement all necessary functions of defined interface:

```
type StringTypeOne string
type StringTypeTwo string


func (s StringTypeOne) DoSomething() {
}

func (s StringTypeTwo) DoSomething() {
}
```

Then you can create function that received interface as parameter:

```
func handleString(s Doer) {
}
```

This method can receive both `StringTypeOne` or `StringTypeTwo` as parameter.

Comment: This does not meet the constraint "any type with a string filed" in "where s can be StringTypeOne or StringTypeTwo or any other type with string field." (or the likely intention of any type with underlying type string).

Comment: @Volker Hm... How about a `Stringer` interface... `func String()string`?

Comment: @Volker In your case, you basically treat all type that underling as string is string. So you can write a function accepted parameter as string. for example: `func handleString(s String) {}` then you can string value from your custom type. For example: `a := StringTypeTwo("example") ; handleString(a.String())`

Answer (score 2):

> Is this possible in golang?

No.

The whole purpose of a new type is that it is a *different* type.

Answer (score 1):

If you really needed this functionality, you could create a new interface type that you then implement for each of your StringTypes, and your function would take an instance of that interface type as it's param.

Comment: i think this is the right answer, would be better if you provided some code examples